# How to send form as json in 11ty

Tags: json, static, directus, eleventy

I'm trying to send data from 11ty to my directus headless CMS.
The problem here is Directus only accepts json data.

No problem to send the data with regular website, but as 11ty is a static site generator, I can't find the way to send the data as json instead of form, because I can only use javascript for receiving data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On your form, why not use JavaScript to handle the form submission and then use fetch() to hit the CMS? Basically, this is something you handle in client-side JS, via your generated site.

Comment: This is something posible with other ssg like gatsby, but not w/ 11ty. Only way to insert javascript functions it is as module.exports to collect api datas, make filters or similar, but not to create functions to be called by click events... This is where I'm stuck. :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. 11ty does not prevent you from using JavaScript in your site. You just.. write it. So if you have foo.liquid, you can include HTML, CSS, and JS in it. 11ty isn't going to stop you from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, Directus provides a collection endpoint, i.e. `/items/contacts` where you can directly POST your form submission.

Comment: Yes, but Directus API is expecting application/json calls, not forms...

Comment: https://github.com/directus/directus/discussions/2719#discussioncomment-17159